# evolution of Grassmannians along geodesic line

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, determinants, grassmannians, homogeneous-spaces, clifford-algebras

Let $p_0$, $p_1$ be two $n \times 2$ orthonormal matrices that represent two points on the real $Gr_{2,n}$, i.e. two 2-d subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $p(t): [0,1] \rightarrow Gr_{2,n}$ be a geodesic line from $p_0$ to $p_1$. With any point $p$ on $Gr_{2,n}$ we associate the $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrix $\Delta(p)$ of its Grassmannians (the $2 \times 2$ minors of $p$). Let $\Delta(t) = \Delta(p(t))$ be the "evolution" curve of the Grassmannians from $\Delta_0 = \Delta(p_0)$ to $\Delta_1 = \Delta(p_1)$. It's well-known that $\Delta(p)$ uniquely identifies $p$ and therefore the curve $\Delta(t)$ is determined by $\Delta_0$, $\Delta_1$ and the geodesic requirement.

> Is there any formula that relates $\left. \frac{d \Delta(t)}{dt} \right|_{t=0}$ to $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_1$ ?

To avoid technical complications we can assume that $p_0$ and $p_1$ are close enough so that the geodesics is unique.

What branch of Math is likely to study this type of questions? Is it Grassmann Algebra, Geometric Algebra, etc? Note that I'm not asking about the geodesics per se, this is well-studied, rather about evolution of the Grassmannians.